Dependency Management in maven
I have a project that uses jar A. Jar A declares B1 (commons-lang3) as a dependency. However, the classes inside jar A import classes from B2 (commons-lang).
If I exclude B1 and include B2 in my project’s dependencies, which dependency will jar A use: B1 or B2?
The issue I’m facing is that jar A’s POM declares commons-lang3, but its classes are trying to use commons-lang. When I run my application, I get an error indicating that a method is not found because the imported classes are from commons-lang, which is not included in the POM.

Are b1 and b2 two different versions of the same dependency?

the case is b1 is common-lang3 and b2 is common-lang. The class files inside jar A are using import from common-lang but the pom inside jar A has commong-lang3 mentioned. Hence when these class files run they say that a particular method is not found because the import from common-lang but common-lang has not been added in pom

If A tries to import classes from common-lang, you either need common-lang or you need to update/replace A.
